# Are My Plants Getting too much Sun?

Tags: plant-health, watering, pruning, sunlight

I have two plants who have been in the sun for less thann 24hrs and their leaves look brown and wilted. The leaves are soft and leathery. I just moved and heard that plants don't like to be moved much, but my nnew place has amazing sunlight so i thought they would like it. Can anyone help me figure out why this happened so quickly?

Thank you!

[image: Monstera Plant Issues 1]

[image: Plant issues 2]

Comment: Did the plants go from growing in shade/indirect light directly to sunlight?

Comment: yes, indirect to now direct.

Answer (score 1):

If they look wilted and dried out and if that's the only thing that's changed for these plants then yes - Monstera Deliciosa which is the top plant that you have there is a tropical plant that lives under tree's canopy's. It loves warm weather and high humidity but it does not like direct intense sunlight. If the light is too intense it definitely could burn the leafs on these.

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure the monstera goes back to indirect light

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a couple of issues here. The first is that you unfortunately moved the plants directly from indirect light to full sun too quickly; like people, leaves can suffer from "sunburn". For example, when I move my seedlings from under lights in the basement to the outdoors in Spring, I first put them in complete shade and then gradually move them into sunlight over the course of 5-7 days (depends on if they like shade or sun outdoors). The second issue is, as TofuGrower says in their answer, the Monstera is a shade-loving plant in its native range- even if you had moved it into sun over a week, it still would've suffered leaf damage (probably crisping). The other plant also looks like a shade lover.

The good news is that the damage is reversible with time - because you've already moved the plants back into indirect light, you'll only lose the leaves, but not the plants.